# Integration testing when the data layer has multiple implementations

Tags: kotlin, integration-testing, graph-databases, vert.x

I have a Kotlin/Vertx API as follows with a graphDB based data repository is injected:

```
class MyServiceAPI : AbstractVerticle() {
   //dependency injection using KodeIn
  val graphRepository: GraphRepository = kodein.instance()

  fun addFriend (friend: User) {
    graphRepository.addFriend(friend)

  }
}
```

GraphRepository has several implementations like `OrientDBGraphRepository, JanusGraphRepository` etc.

I want to add integration tests using in-memory DB instances. I have following questions:

1. Do I need to write separate integration tests for each DB implementation or should I pass the params(hostname, user, password) of the DB configuration to change the implementation accordingly?
2. Since I have coded for the repo interface, do I need to I instantiate each implementation for each case when testing them?

Apologies if this is opinion based, any insight would be appreciated.